# NoSQL Document DB

Tags: mongodb, couchdb, nosql

I am in a need for a document-oriented database for a project I am working on. I basically have two things I need: Full ACID support and the ability to have references. Scalability is not a major issue since the number of total users is at most 300.

I know MongoDB supports references between documents and CouchDB supports ACID but I have not found one that has both.

I am really trying to avoid implementing either (ACID, References) in the application layer. The obvious fallback is RDBMS with some tree structure implementation which I am also trying to avoid.

Any suggestions?

THANX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You require ACID and full references, and CouchDB is *not* good for that.

You *do not* require scalability either. My guess is a database that is well-known wouldn't hurt either.

For those reasons, a relational database sounds appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

Checkout [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net) - it has both ACID and transaction support AND it supports the notion of relations between documents via Includes and Live Projections. Denormalization can probably come in handy, too.

Don't use an RDBMS if your business logic says it doesn't like it.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned the constraints - you mentioned correctly what CouchDB/MongoDB give you.
So based on those facts: use your fallback.

Comment: I have asked for a solution that I haven't found myself. I know that there are a lot of NoSQL projects out there and I was wondering if anyone knows one that will suit my needs. Maybe a library that is built on top of CouchDB or MongoDB the enables what the db doesn't.

Comment: thank you! I know about CAP theorem. But it deals with distributed computing. I didn't ask for a scale-out solution, in fact I specifically said that it is not a requirement. I am not asking for anything a relational database is not doing already. I need ACID+Relational+Document(Instead of rows) which is possible even with CAP theorem.

Comment: @Sonia - It sounds like you want to use a document database for the simple reason it's the new fad at the moment... It doesn't suit your requirements so your better off just using a normal relational database.